# Fix Safari Error: "Fetch API cannot load... due to access control checks"

Tags: firebase, safari, fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit

I'm creating a basic Sveltekit app with Firebase Authentication (with Google).

In Chrome all works fine, but in Safari (desktop + mobile) I'm getting the following error:

```
"Fetch API cannot load... due to access control checks". It seems to be related to Firebase initialization."
```

Would truly appreciate your help